# Using Like operator to work through different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different workbooks that will be generated and kept open. The names have either "outbound" or "inbound" and then the date and time. E.g "data-details-outbound 2019-03-07..." and "data-details-inbound 2019-03-07...". I need different code to be performed on each worksheet, so I need my code to differentiate between the two.

I have the following code, but when I run it it just does all the actions on whatever workbook is activated.

```
Sub NotifiedReminderEmail()
'
' Current issue is the LIKE operator is choosing whatever wb is open, not the correct one.
'
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim owbName As String
    Dim iwbName As String

    owbName = "outbound"
    iwbName = "inbound"

    'sets up the OB sheet
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & owbName & "*" Then
            Debug.Print wb.Name
            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                'perform code
            End With
        End If
    Next wb

    'sets up the IB sheet
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like "*" & iwbName & "*" Then
            Debug.Print wb.Name
            With wb.Worksheets(1)
                'perform code
            End With
        End If
    Next wb

End Sub
```

Comment: Switch them, `if "*" & iwbName & "*" Like wb.Name`. Edit: Also you can join both loops in one by using Else.

Comment: You say you have "two different workbooks that will be generated and kept open. The names have either "outbound" or "inbound"" so that suggests both will be operated upon?

Comment: @RicardoA - think it's ok as it is? Agree about the loop though.

Comment: @Richardo A: switching them seemed to make the if statement always be false. It just skipped to the end without executing any code.

Comment: @SJR: Yes, that is correct. Both workbooks will need some code to be performed on each. It's different code, so it needs to pick the correct one.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see what's going on? Without knowing what the code being performed I don't know how you can tell the difference.

Comment: @SJR: The code being performed is pretty basic data cleanup stuff, deleting columns, etc. I'm going to eventually add in an auto email when I get the Like operator functioning correctly. When I step through the code it goes through a few loops of the For operator, but when it finally steps into the If statement it just does the data cleanup on the workbook that I have activated. It's almost as if it sees that I have a workbook open with "outbound", but it doesn't care to step into that workbook.

Comment: Presumably it goes through 2 iterations? Does it print the correct name to the immediate window?

Comment: Yeah it's printing the correct name in the immediate window: "train-details-outbound - 2019-03-07T090203.487.csv". Do you think it has to do with the .csv?

Comment: @SJR: I know it's frowned upon, but I just added in a wb.Activate before the with statement and it worked. I don't know what else to do, but let me know if you come up with something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes you shouldn't need to activate. It might be because they're csvs. Try it with a couple of xls files or open the csv files via VBA and then you can set workbook references.